# How to resolve the issue while trying to test my contract

Tags: testing, truffle-test, mocha

I'm new to blockchain development and can't figure out what I have done wrong. This is my smart contract Election :

```
    pragma solidity ^0.5.0;


contract Election {
    struct Candidate {
        uint id;
        string name;
        uint votecount;
    
    }
    
mapping (uint => Candidate) public candidates;
uint public candidateCount;

  constructor() public {
  a=5;
   addCandidate("Candidate 1");
   addCandidate("Candidate 2");
  }
  function addCandidate (string memory _name)  private {
    candidateCount++;
    candidates[candidateCount]=Candidate(candidateCount,_name,0);

  }

 
}
```

This is a javascript file to test if there are exactly two candidates:

```
var elec=artifacts.require("./Election.sol");
contract("Election",function(accounts){
    it("initialised with two candidates", function(){
         var a;
        return Election.deployed().then(function(instance)
        {

            return instance.candidateCount.call();

        }).then(function(count){
            assert.equal(count.toNumber(),2);
        });

    });

});
```

[image]

This is the error I'm getting. Somebody please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
var elec = artifacts.require("./Election.sol");
```

To this:

```
var Election = artifacts.require("./Election.sol");
```

Or this:

```
Election.deployed()
```

To this:

```
elec.deployed()
```

---

Note that `artifacts.require` takes as input a contract name, not a file path.

So you can get rid of the `./` part and the `.sol` part in the string that you are passing to it.